# Is there a tool that identifies the zip codes inside an area/circle?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

not sure if this is the place to answer this question, but is there a tool that can help me identify the zip codes inside an area? like I would plot a circle in a map and then it will give me the zip codes that are inside that cirle

Answer (score 1):

It is possible however, the first problem you might encounter would be what if the `circle` or `area` you plot span across 2 different postal code?

Assuming we are talking about looking up a postal code for the `lat` and `lng` of an area's centre point then you can make use of google map's "Reverse Geocoding Latitude/Longitude" service.

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-example

> **Reverse Geocoding for a Latitude/Longitude**
>
> The following query contains the latitude/longitude value for a
>   location in Brooklyn:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY 
>   Note: Ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude
>   values when passed in the latlng parameter.

**Example:**
My current coordinates is at `-27.497755,152.971700`

So my request would be:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-27.497755,152.971700

This basically returns me a set of matched "address_components" in JSON object form. These object shares the same postal code and are just neighbor to your current location; so you should be able to use anyone of their postal code.

```js
$.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-27.497755,152.971700", function(data, status){
    if (status === "success") {
        var postalComp = data.results[0].address_components.find(comp => { return (comp.types[0] ==="postal_code")});
        console.log("My postal code is: " + postalComp.long_name);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```